# PhoneGap open documents from website

Tags: android, iphone, ios, cordova

I'm trying to open documents from a remote server in a PhoneGap app (2.8.1), on both iOS and Android. On iOS it is working with the following piece code:

```
window.open(documentUrl, '_blank', 'location=no');
```

Unfortunately this is not working on the Android platform (I see a white screen instead of the document). At the moment iOS is opening the documents within the InAppBrowser (for example a pdf, txt, doc document) does anybody know how to make this work on the Android platform? If possible I would also prefer to ask the user to send the document to an installed app that supports the mime/content type is this also possible?

Comment: On iOS, I don't see a close button even if I have location set to "yes".  How are you closing the document after seeing it?

Answer (score 0):

It's working perfectly for me on android,

The only difference, is that im using it as a var, so i can add eventlisteners into it, Example:

```
 mywindow = window.open('http://xxxxxx/hi.php', '_blank', 'location=no');
```

then u can add events like exit for example, so u know when that window is closed, else there is no way you can get back to your app, :

```
mywindow.addEventListener('exit', myexitfunc);
```

**#Edit1**: Make sure jQuery is loading before you attempt `window.open`